# Delays in node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

How would you go about introducing a delay between the two emits below:

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(8092);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {  
    socket.emit('foo', ["data1"]);
    socket.emit('foo', ["data2"]);
});
```

I want to create a simple server simulator which outputs data at different points in time.

Comment: just do a `setTimeout`?

Comment: Is your delay time? Is it based on another condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(8092);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  socket.emit('foo', ["data1"]);

  setTimeout(() => {
    socket.emit('foo', ["data2"]);
  }, 1500); // change the 1500 to whatever time delay you want in milliseconds
});
```

Reference: [NodeJS timers](https://nodejs.org/docs/v5.5.0/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg)